# Pig default JsonLoader schema issue

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've the below data that need to be parsed using Pig

**Data**

```
{
    "Name": "BBQ Chicken",
    "Sizes": [
        { "Size": "Large", "Price": 14.99 },
        { "Size": "Medium", "Price": 12.99 }
    ],
    "Toppings": [ "Barbecue Sauce", "Chicken", "Cheese" ]
}
```

I am able to define the schema for `Name` and `Sizes` but I couldn't get the `Toppings` working. Looking for some help here.

**Script**

```
data = LOAD '/user/hue/data/nested_json_pizza_sample_data.json'
       USING JsonLoader('Name:chararray,
                         Sizes:bag{tuple(Size:chararray, Price:float)},
                         Toppings:tuple(a:chararray)');
DUMP data;
```

**Output**

As you can see below, the Topping's data is not being parsed.

```
(BBQ Chicken,{(Large,14.99),(Medium,12.99)},)
(Hawaiian,{(Large,12.99),(Medium,10.99)},)
(Vegetable,{(Large,12.99),(Medium,10.99)},)
(Pepperoni,{(Large,12.99),(Medium,10.99),(Small,7.49)},)
(Cheese,{(Large,10.99),(Medium,9.99),(Small,5.49)},)
data: {Name: chararray,Sizes: {(Size: chararray,Price: float)},Toppings: (a: chararray)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here : if the number of items in the array in unknown.

```
Toppings:{t:(i:chararray)}
```

Or if the number of elements going to be same allways.

```
Toppings: (i: chararray, j: chararray, k: chararray)
```

will give you output :

```
(BBQ Chicken,{(Large,14.99),(Medium,12.99)},)
```

Comment: I've tried Toppings:{t:(i:chararray)} but the output is same as I've shown in the original post. Since the toppings are not fixed, I can't use the 2nd option but I've tried it too and the output is the same.

Comment: That is strange since I tried it out locally and i got the output as I have given in the answer

Comment: could you please share which version of pig you are using and also are you running it from grunt? Are you using the sandbox of Cloudera or Hortonworks. The issue I've is on Hortonworks sandbox 2.

Comment: Apache Pig version 0.12.0 (r1529718) and Hadoop 1.2.1 running in pseudo dist mode.