# pig jsonloader array parse issue

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a json encoded data below need to be parsed using pig.

{"arr":[1,2,3,4]}

According a document at http://help.mortardata.com/technologies/pig/json#toc_4JsonLoaderSchemaGuidelines
, 
my loading schema is:

```
a = load 'testJsonPig.log' using JsonLoader('arr:{t:(i:int)}');
```

and dump it:

```
dump a;
```

but I got an unepected result:

```
()
```

the result is empty, and I don't know why it happened, It seemed that I met a same question as this link
[Pig default JsonLoader schema issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076583/pig-default-jsonloader-schema-issue?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
 described.

My pig version is

> Apache Pig version 0.12.1 (r1585011)

and wish someone could help me, thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I use elephantbird jsonloader to solve my problem.

https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/

Answer (score 1):

[PIG-2949](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2949) was an issue that described this problem. It was resolved and should work as of Pig 0.15.0 out-of-the-box. So yes - as the OP discovered - elephantbird is the only easy way to handle such arrays *now*, but soon Pig will be able to handle them natively.

(full disclosure - I closed this issue myself)

Comment: Pig 0.15 was released [on June 6th, 2015](http://pig.apache.org/releases.html#6+June%2C+2015%3A+release+0.15.0+available), so it should work if you use it.

Comment: I had some doubts about the syntax, used the one in the question itself which works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`arr:bag{a:tuple(a:int)}` should work.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

the bag and tuple keywords in the above solution could be skipped.

```
a = load 'testJsonPig.log' using JsonLoader('arr:{(int)}');
DUMP a;
```

output:
({(1),(2),(3),(4)})

creates a bag of tuples, each containing 1 element.